# Churchill Solitaire scoring

Tags: scoring, solitaire

In theory, one scores 5 points for each card moved from the "devil's 6" and 1 point for each of the other cards. So a win should score 98 + 30 = 128 (ignoring any bonus for winning in a short time). Yet my score for a win is sometimes less than 128 and sometimes more.  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score -1):

Churchill solitaire also awards points for cards moved by the game when cleaning up — the more it cleans up for you, the larger the bonus.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).